# Creating a Ruby Gem with web-server

Tags: ruby, rubygems, webserver, sinatra

I'm about to begin working on a Gem for Ruby (not necessarily for web application).
My Gem will require a web interface for controlling the Gem. The web interface must have some basic authentication and authorization.

I know Sinatra is lite, but are there other (smaller) web-servers that meet the requirements?

**Edit:**

I should elaborate: By controlling interface I meant an interface for viewing and editing DB (probably Redis) rows. Super simple.

Comment: you can use EventMachine - it could work with async operations

Comment: Sorry @IgorPavlov, I should have been elaborated more (post edited). Your suggestion is an overkill but I'm glad I had a chance to learn what EventMachine is.

Comment: er... so https://github.com/monterail/redis-browser - i think that you were looking for such thing

Comment: @IgorPavlov, yep. Already forked it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to build your own web server using rack 
http://rack.github.io/

Comment: I thought about it and realized that building my own web-server will take more time than building the gem.